# Package development in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to start in the package development world. For educational purposes. I've had some troubles to find a good up-to-date documentation or tutorial in this matter.

I want to develop these packages that you add into de config/app.php file, and give the alias. I've found something about a "workbench" tool that is not available anymore.

Anywho, can someone lit up the road a little bit?

Thank you so much.

Comment: did you follow https://laracasts.com/lessons/package-development-101

Comment: It was made in 2013, don't you think it is deprecated? Or the workflow is the same?

Comment: Workflow is the same and logic is still applicable.

Comment: Ok, ok, thanks. I'm gonna check it out.